# conditional probability with complements, false negative

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

given $P(T|D) = .95, P(T|D^c) = .1 , P(D) = .01$ I found $P(D|T) = .904762$ and I want to find $P(D|T^c)$ but I am unsure how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: Given $\mathbb P(D\mid T) = 0.95$ you found that $\mathbb P(D\mid T) = 0.087557$? Clearly something is amiss.

Comment: shoot! i mis-typed. it should be $P(T|D) =.95$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, start by noticing that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(D|T^{c}) = \frac{\textbf{P}(D\cap T^{c})}{\textbf{P}(T^{c})} = \frac{\textbf{P}(D) - \textbf{P}(D\cap T)}{1 - \textbf{P}(T)}
\end{align*}
This is because
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(D) = \textbf{P}(D\cap\Omega) = \textbf{P}(D\cap(T\cup T^{c})) = \textbf{P}(D\cap T) + \textbf{P}(D\cap T^{c})
\end{align*}
Based on the given data, one has
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\textbf{P}(T|D) = \frac{\textbf{P}(T\cap D)}{\textbf{P}(D)} = 0.95\\\\
\displaystyle\textbf{P}(T|D^{c}) = \frac{\textbf{P}(T\cap D^{c})}{\textbf{P}(D^{c})} = \frac{\textbf{P}(T) - \textbf{P}(T\cap D)}{1 - \textbf{P}(D)} = 0.1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Since you know the value $\textbf{P}(D) = 0.01$, you can solve the system of equations in terms of $\textbf{P}(T)$ and $\textbf{P}(D\cap T)$. To be precise, this is the system of equations
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\textbf{P}(D\cap T) = 0.95\times\textbf{P}(D) = 0.0095\\\\
\displaystyle\textbf{P}(T) - \textbf{P}(T\cap D) = 0.099
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: post edited to contain correct values

Answer (score 0):

> given $P(T|D) = .95, P(T|D^c) = .1 , P(D) = .01$

With this, it is straightforward.

Just do the same as you did to find that $P(D\mid T)=1/12$, remembering that $P(T^c\mid D)=1-P(T\mid D)$.

---

$\begin{align}P(T) &=P(T\mid D)\cdot P(D)+P(T\mid D^c)\cdot (1-P(D))
\\[2ex] P(D\mid T) &=\dfrac{P(D)\cdot P(T\mid D)}{P(T)}&&=\tfrac 1{12} ~\checkmark
\\[2ex]P(D\mid T^c)&= \dfrac{P(D)\cdot(1-P(T\mid D))}{1-P(T)}\end{align}$